# How to overload the conditional operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, conditional-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

I was wonder how can I over load the Conditional operator in cpp?

```
int a,b,c;

  a=10;
  b=11;
  c = (a>b) ? a : b;
```

Is it possible?

Comment: why do you want to overload it??

Comment: [This FAQ entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421715#4421715) explains that you cannot do that. Voting to close this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several operators cannot be overloaded. These operators take a name, rather than an object, as their right operand:

- Direct member access (.)
- Deference pointer to class member (.*)
- Scope resolution (::)
- Size of (sizeof)

The **conditional operator (?:)** also cannot be overloaded.

Additionally, the new typecast operators: static_cast<>, dynamic_cast<>, reinterpret_cast<>, and const_cast<>, and the # and ## preprocessor tokens cannot be overloaded.

http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=23

Comment: I'm not sure I'd agree with the statement that the operators you can't overload "take a name, rather than an object, as their right operand".  The operator `.*` takes an arbitrary expression as its right operand, and `->` (which you can overload) takes a name.  The difference is slightly different: `::` is a compile time operator, controlling name lookup, so overloading it makes no sense; `sizeof` can be used in constant expressions, and `?:` would require some special syntax and additional rules. `.` and `.*` are simply arbitrary choices.

Comment: "new typecast operators"? What language are you talking about? They've always been in Standard C++...

Comment: I remember overloading unary left `*`, how's that different from what you denote as `.*`?

Answer (score 7):

You cannot overload the conditional operator.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't overload the conditional operator, since it's simply shorthand for a simple `if..else` block.

You can however overload the operators used in the condition, but not for primitive types such as `int`, like you have in your example above.

Comment: The conditional operator is actually not shorthand. `if...else` blocks switch between zero or more statements (full lines of code), whereas the conditional operator switches between two expressions.